# Live Chat - users can't create a New case from a transcript?

Tags: chat

Is there a way to allow users to create a New Case from a Chat Transcript?

For example the layout below shows the chat in progress but the Case Details and lookup doesn't offer a user the ability to create a case during a chat?  The only option is to navigate to the Case Object and choose New in a different window.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are Service Cloud Chat API methods that you can use after chat finishes. Check the page 40 of the developer guide. You will need a Visualforce component. [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_creating_records_API_findOrCreate.htm)

Comment: Great thanks - automates the whole thing too which will make the agents happy!

Comment: Make sure you check out the sample code and iterate based on the example, some chat API methods are tricky!